# How do I break rocks?

Tags: tower-of-fantasy

[image: Large cracked boulders blocking a treasure]

As you can see in the screenshot, these large cracked boulder are hiding a supply pod which is hidden behind.

How can I smash these boulders and retrieve the treasure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to break rocks you need the Barrage relic. This relic is obtained through the main campaign story missions.

[image: Barrage relic]